# Can't display product categories on woocommerce getting Invalid taxonomy?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am tried to display all product category with bellow function .. getting a error Invalid taxonomy .. it's was working fine last 2 installation..

```
    function be_woocommerce_category_id(){
        $categories_array = array();
        $categories_array[0] = esc_html__('Choose a Category', 'shopstore'); 
        $args = array(
                    'orderby'    => 'title',
                    'order'      => 'ASC',
                );
        $categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

        if( count($categories) > 0 ){
            foreach( $categories as $category ){
              $categories_array[$category->term_id] = $category->name; 
            }
        }
        return $categories_array; 
}
```

Comment: Where and when are you running this function?

Comment: it's default woocomerce hook

Comment: Which hook? Specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it's was working fine last 2 installation

Those two installation *might* still be on WordPress prior to version 4.5.0, and according to the [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/):

> Since 4.5.0, taxonomies should be passed via the ‘taxonomy’ argument
>   in the `$args` array

So:

```
$args = array(
  'orderby'  => 'title',
  'order'    => 'ASC',
  'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
);
$categories = get_terms( $args );
```

If that doesn't work, then maybe on the new installation, your code is executed before the `product_cat` taxonomy is registered.

Comment: it's showing object(WP_Error)#808 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["invalid_taxonomy"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(17) "Invalid taxonomy." } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: WooCommerce [registers](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Post_types.html#27) its custom taxonomies during the init hook with `5` being the priority. So if your code is called from a hook (action/filter), then make sure the hook is fired after `init` or that the priority is at least `6`. And FYI, the taxonomies are not yet registered in either the `woocommerce_loaded` or `woocommerce_init` hook/action.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same 'problem' a few days ago. Like Sally CJ edited, this may be a registration issue. 
When I called `term_exists()`, the expected term_id was returned, but `get_term()` returned the Invalid taxonomy error.  
*My solution* was to call the [register_taxonomy function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) in my function and everything was fine.  
Edit:  
I called it like that (with an empty array as $args):

```
register_taxonomy( 'taxonomy_name', array('the_custom_post_type'), array() );
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. For Woocomerce you can be resolved by adding the below code in **functions.php**:

```
register_taxonomy( 'product_cat', array('product'), array() );
```